# ¿Como implementar la propiedad elevation en api 19 e inferiores?

Tags: android, android-layout

Ando haciendo un proyecto en android studio y quiero utilizar la propiedad `elevation` para unos `LinearLayout` pero como la app también va a estar dirigida a versiones inferiores del la api 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar esto se tiene que simular la elevación:

Puedes definir como `background` a tu vista este `Shape`:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
```

Este sería el archivo `my_background.xml` que se crea dentro del folder `/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item
android:left="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:bottom="2dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Otro método conocido es agregar como background el drawable `dialog_holo_light_frame` del SDK :

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Con ambas opciones puedes obtener algo similar a la propiedad `elevation`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tercera opción es es crear un Drawable 9 patch cuya imagen contiene la sombra de elevación y la cual usarías como background de tu vista:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow/25683148#25683148

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]